# continuously redirect console output onto web page using flask

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

I am new to flask, I am trying to write a web app that continuously redirects stdout to web page. 
For example:-

```
stdout:-
line1
line2 
line3
.....
```

Is there a way so that i can display the same on a web page each time a new line is written to stdout incrementally along with the previous content still being there ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not (normally) a code writing service. However, we'll gladly help you when you get stuck. Show us the code that you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can return a string under a view function in flask for just basic stuff (i.e. "hello world").

If you capture the output of your script/function as a string, you should be able to simply return it under whatever view function is being called to present the page.